# Using a custom view in multiple adapters

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a custom view that I need to be able to use in two different adapters.

Here is the custom view's layout (`custom_view.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the custom view's class (`CustomView.java`):

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {
    private final String TAG = "CustomView";

    private User user;

    private RelativeLayout container;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, User user) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.user = user;
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, User user) {
        super(context);
        this.user = user;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_view, this);

        container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        avatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imaveView);
        displayName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // Add the user profile picture to the imageView
        Glide.with(getContext())
                .load("http://www.website.com/img/users/" + user.getId() + "/avatar.png")
                .into(imageView);

        // Set the user username in the textView
        textView.setText(user.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Now, I need to use the custom view in two different adapters.

The first adapter I need to use the custom view in is a regular `RecyclerView` adapter, which currently looks like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";

    private Context context;

    private List<User> userData;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<User> userData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // TODO: WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // TODO: WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userData.size();
    }
}
```

How can I inflate the custom view in this class and how can I bind the `userData` to it?

The second adapter I need to use the custom view in is an adapter for the [AndroidTreeView library](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView).

Here is my adapter (so far) for the AndroidTreeView library:

```
public class CustomTreeAdapter extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<CustomTreeAdapter.TreeItem> {
    public CustomTreeAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View createNodeView(TreeNode node, TreeItem value) {
        // TODO: WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
    }

    public static class TreeItem {
        // TODO: WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
    }
}
```

For reference, here is the [integration documentation](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView#integration) for the AndroidTreeView library.

What should I put in the methods above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For RecyclerView, in your onCreateViewHolder() I'd put this:

```java
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);
    return new CustomViewHolder(view);
}
```

And then, to bind data from userData to your ViewHolder, put this for onBindViewHolder():

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(userData.get(position).getName());
}
```

Of course, this means you need to have find the TextView in your ViewHolder first:

```
class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    CustomViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

At least I think this is how you'd do it with the RecyclerView and ViewHolder, I think you might want to move your code in CustomView class like init() into ViewHolder maybe.

Comment: I already set all my textview text in the custom view class, so it doesn't make sense to me to do `setText()` again in the ViewHolder.

Comment: But I thought ViewHolder is where you're supposed to set the views for your item/row?

Comment: Doing `setText()` twice, once in each adapter, doesn't make sense if I can do it once in the custom view class.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish; can you clear it up a bit?

Comment: I have a custom view, where I set all my data. I want to use this custom view in two different adapters (as shown above). How do I do this?

Comment: I supposed you could have your ViewHolder as maybe a non-static outer class, and have each adapter inflate your custom_view and use the same ViewHolder. But I don't know much about how that's done, whether if that's recommended practice or if it may or may not cause memory leak. Sorry I wasn't much help.